# Disabling selected cells on react full calendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I have an array named publicholidays

```
const publicholidays = [
  { title: "Republic Day", date: "2023-01-26", backgroundColor: "grey" },
  { title: "Maudy Thursday", date: "2023-04-06", backgroundColor: "grey" },
  { title: "Good Friday", date: "2023-04-07", backgroundColor: "grey" },
  { title: "Ramzan", date: "2023-04-21", backgroundColor: "grey" },
  { title: "May Day", date: "2023-05-01", backgroundColor: "grey" },
  { title: "Bakri Id", date: "2023-07-04", backgroundColor: "grey" },
  { title: "Independence Day", date: "2023-08-15", backgroundColor: "grey" },
  { title: "1st Onam", date: "2023-08-28", backgroundColor: "grey" },
  { title: "Thiruonam", date: "2023-08-29", backgroundColor: "grey" },
  { title: "Gandhi Jayanthi", date: "2023-10-02", backgroundColor: "grey" },
  { title: "Vijaya Dashami", date: "2023-10-24", backgroundColor: "grey" },
  { title: "Christmas Day", date: "2023-12-25", backgroundColor: "grey" },
  { title: "Christmas Day", date: "2023-12-26", backgroundColor: "grey" },
];
```

I want to disable this cells, the click functions should not work on this cells

i wrote a function

```
  const disableHolidays = (info) => {
    debugger
    const dateStr = info.date.toISOString().slice(0,10); // Get the date string of the current day cell
    const holiday = publicholidays.find(holiday => holiday.date === dateStr); // Check if the current day cell is a holiday
    if (holiday) {
      const cell = info.el?.querySelector('.fc-daygrid-day-content');
      cell.classList.add('disabled'); // Add a CSS class to the day cell to make it disabled
      // Disable the click event on the day cell
      cell.onclick = function() {
        return false;
      };
    }
  };
```

and in the full calendar i used dayCellContent={disableHolidays} and called the function but its not disabling the cell and i am getting errors, how can i fix that.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose the issue just by looking at this. Could you please share the code for the entire component?

Comment: the component code is too long i am not able to share that in comments. i need to disable the cells which has public holidays,no click functions should work on that cell

Comment: <FullCalendar
 plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
 selectLongPressDelay={null} 
  initialView="dayGridMonth"
        editable={true}
        selectable={true}
         dayCellContent={disableHolidays}
        weekends={false}
        selectMirror={true}
        events={selectedDates.map((d) => ({
          ...d,
          title: d.reason,
          classNames: [d.dayType],
        }))}
        select={handleDateClick}
        eventContent={renderEventContent}
        eventDidMount={eventDidMount}
        eventWillUnmount={eventWillUnmount}
      />

Comment: Don't share code in the comments, instead please [edit] your question. As you're new, please also take the [tour] and read [ask] so you know how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway a better solution would be to check these dates in the `handleDateClick`1 function and just don't proceed if the clicked date matches any of them. Or you can consider doing that via the [selectAllow](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow) option. P.S. It's unclear what you expect to happen if a user selects multiple dates in a single selection? Should it disallow the selection if any of the selected date range intersects with your list of public holidays?

Comment: P.P.S. You can also make it easier for users to see what dates are not allowed (and make it easier to ban selection) by putting these as a feed of Background Events into your calendar display, so they can see those dates are in a different colour.